# android- changes to be made in AndroidManifest.xml while calling intent

Tags: android, android-intent

wat changes do i hav 2 make in AndroidManifest.xml if am calling an intent....

m calling Intent frm an Inner class method defined inside class which extends name test.java
i wanna disply content mentioned in class named Test2.java......

n both classes r in same package.....

n hw can i define textvies n radiobuttons n othr stuff on dat new intent...
how do i exactly do it???

Comment: By the way... this is not twitter (no need to cut your words), this is not myspace or a forum or 4chan, etc. So please try to write better.

Comment: ya sure.....
thnk u 4 advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest, add this element as a child of the `application` element

```
<activity android:name=".Test2"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is adding the Activity element to your AndroidManifest.xml. For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.foo">
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".Test1" android:label="Your first activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Test2" android:label="Your second activity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In order to define `TextView`s and stuff, well I recommend you to first read the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html